# How to check the status of orchestration instances inside an orchestrator function in Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable function with OrchestrationA and OrchestrationB functions.
Something like this:

```
[FunctionName("OrchestratorA")]
public static async Task OrchestratorA(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        /*
         * Applay some logic to check if there is already running insance with an instance id
         * starting with $"OrchestratorB_{i}"
         */
        context.StartNewOrchestration("OrchestratorB", null, $"OrchestratorB_{i}_{Guid.NewGuid}");
    }
}


[FunctionName("OrchestratorA_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OrchestratorA_HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Function input comes from the request content.
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestratorA", null);

    log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

I'm having difficulty determining how to check the status of currently running instances within the OrchestratorA function. While there are numerous examples using IDurableOrchestrationClient from the HttpStart function, I cannot seem to find a solution while inside an Orchestration context with IDurableOrchestrationContext.

Answer (score 2):

The methods on `IDurableOrchestrationClient` would not be [deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints?tabs=csharp), so you would have to create [activity functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions) that can use the input binding and return the status of the orchestration.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Functions
{
    public static class DurableFunctions
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(RunOrchestrator))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(GetStatus), context.InstanceId));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!", "Running"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(SayHello))]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(GetStatus))]
        public static async Task<string> GetStatus([ActivityTrigger] string id, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client, ILogger log)
        {
            var runtimeStatus = (await client.GetStatusAsync(id)).RuntimeStatus.ToString();

            log.LogInformation("Status of orchestration instance {id} is {runtimeStatus}.", id, runtimeStatus);
            return runtimeStatus;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(StartOrchestrator))]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> StartOrchestrator(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(RunOrchestrator), null);

            log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean just create an activity and make an http request to check instance status o what? I thought to solve in that way but seems not practical. I should add somewhere the base function address and seems hacky solution. Please could you give me some pseudo code of what are you talking about?

Comment: You don't need to make an HTTP Request. In the activity function, bind to the `IDurableOrchestrationClient` like the HTTP Starter function and use those APIs to get the status. I've updated my answer to include a sample.